# Archivo txt no almacena la ruta de otro txt

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

Lo que trato de hacer es crear 2 archivos en sistema, una en donde el usuario pueda escoger en donde quiera guardar su archivo database en donde estarán todos los registros de sus productos. El otro archivo `txt` se crearía sin el permiso del usuario y ya estará ubicado en el disco `C`, el punto es que este archivo tendrá almacenado la ruta del archivo txt de la base de datos.

El único problema que presento es que el archivo que creo sin el permiso del usuario es que no almacena la ruta del archivo de la base de datos.

```
private void btnRuta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

    //Aquí creo 2 variables que serian archivos .txt, creo una para la base de datos en un grid y otra que me almacene la ruta de esta base de dato.
    string dataBase;
    string rutaDataBase = @"Bibliotecas\Documentos\rutaDataBase.txt";

            SaveFileDialog salvarArchivo = new SaveFileDialog();
            salvarArchivo.Filter = "archivo de texto|*.txt";

            if (salvarArchivo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {

                dataBase = new FileInfo(salvarArchivo.FileName).DirectoryName;

                StreamWriter escritor = new StreamWriter(salvarArchivo.FileName);

                escritor.Write(dataBase);//Aqui si funciona, pero el punto es que salga en el otro archivo txt.

                escritor.Close();

                System.IO.File.CreateText(rutaDataBase).Write(dataBase); //AQUÍ ES DONDE NO ME ESCRIBE LA RUTA DE MI DATABASE EN MI ARCHIVO DE TEXTO


            }

        }
```

Comment: La ruta c:\ no es muy buena idea y si usas Windows 8/10 tienes que tener permisos de administrador, Has probado guardarle en otro sitio?

Comment: Ahora lo intento, pero solo viene a ser por eso? Entonces lo pondria en el descargar. Lo que hago es solo un pequeño proyecto para usarlo a futuro.

Comment: Siempre lo recomendable es que escribas en mis documentos, o por algún lado en el perfil del usuario actual (que vos sepas que tiene permiso en esa ruta)

Comment: Y si pruebas guardar la ruta en los settings de la aplicacion, te dejo el [enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa730869(v=vs.80)), quizas te ayude y asi no debes de crear un archivo aparte.

Comment: Me salta este error cuando le pongo que se guardará en documentos:

Comment: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'No se puede encontrar una parte de la ruta de acceso 'C:\Users\gpoma.SANBORJA\Downloads\Proyecto 29 de noviembre\Proyecto_29_de_noviembre\Proyecto_29_de_noviembre\bin\Debug\Bibliotecas\Documentos\rutaDataBase.txt'.'

Comment: string ruta = @"Bibliotecas\Documentos\rutaDataBase.txt";

Comment: Por el nombre de la excepcion es que no encontro ningun directorio o carpeta con esa direccion, porque no actualizas el codigo que ya tienes en la pregunta.

Comment: Ya esta, perdón por eso,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ocurre que no estás guardando el archivo en la ruta de documentos, sino en una ruta relativa a la *carpeta actual* de tu aplicación.

Si quieres guardarlo en documentos, debes interrogar al sistema para obtener la ruta, por ejemplo:

```
String pathDoc = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
String rutaDatabase = Path.Combine(pathDoc, 'rutaDataBase.txt');
```

**Edición:**

De los comentarios veo que tienes también dificultad con guardar el archivo, lo que ocurre es, como ya comentó @Orlando, es que no cierras el archivo.

Para poder cerrarlo, recomiendo que almacenes una referencia a la variable, por ejemplo:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter dbsw = ystem.IO.File.CreateText(rutaDataBase);
dbsw.Write(dataBase);
dbsw.Close();
```

Comment: gracias por tu solución y por tus buenas prácticas , pero lamentablemente aún no se puede guardar los datos que yo quiero en mi archivo .txt

Comment: Este código es el que me tenía que salvar, pero lo unico que hace es crear y NO almacenarme los datos que le paso =>
                           
 System.IO.File.CreateText(rutaDatabase).Write(dataBase);

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal recuerda hacer el `Close` del archivo que estas creando, asi como haces con la variable `escritor`, de lo contrario nunca guardara nada, se creara un archivo vacio.

Comment: Cierto, ahora lo implemento... Por cierto, gracias por seguirme ayudando :)

Comment: Me sale este error => System.IO.IOException: 'El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo 'C:\Users\gpoma.SANBORJA\Documents\rutaDataBase.txt' porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso.'

Comment: Y el codigo que implemente fue este => System.IO.File.CreateText(rutaDatabase).Close();

Comment: @GianFrancoAlexisPomaVidal, he editado mi respuesta para orientarte también sobre como guardar la cadena.

Comment: FUNCIONOOOOOOOO!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: GRACIAS AMIGAZO @jachguate, SIN TI NO LO HUBIERA LOGRADO